# Overload resolution of int vs std::vector<int> with an initializer list of a single int

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, overloading, initializer-list, overload-resolution

Why does c++ choose a primitive type overload match over a "better" matching initializer list?

```cpp
#include <vector>

void foo([[maybe_unused]] int i) {}

void foo([[maybe_unused]] const std::vector<int>& v) {}

int main() {
    foo(0);
    foo({1,2,3});
    foo({0}); // calls foo(int) and issues a warning,
              // rather than what seems like the "better"
              // match foo(vector).. why? 
}
```

```
<source>:10:9: warning: braces around scalar initializer [-Wbraced-scalar-init]
    foo({0}); // calls foo(int) and issues a warning,
        ^~~
```

Perhaps "surprising" result, since the compiler chooses the option for which it then issues a diagnostic?

Using Clang 14

https://godbolt.org/z/1dscc5hM4

Comment: Not really. You're telling to construct something that can be constructed from an int and that that can be fed to call `foo`.
Well, an int fills that role.

Comment: not surprising to me. (btw, if you really have `std::initializer_list<int>` as title it'd win)

Comment: You probably want to have a `std::initializer_list` like `void foo([[maybe_unused const std::initializer_list<int>& list){}`, to force `{0}` to be interpreted as an `std::initializer_list` when possible.

Comment: @Lærne but that's what constructor #10 of std::vector takes? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: Why would the compiler pick a `std::vector<int>` when picking `int`, it can call foo without creating any intermediate type ? The rule of forcing usage of a `std::initializer_list` only works for the function/constructor that is explicitly called, not for intermediate types. Else you could argue arbitrary creation of intermediate types, e.g. that it should build a `std::array<int, 1>` to build to build a `std::deque<int>` to build a `std::vector<int>` to call `foo`.

Comment: `int` fits the role with the least amount of casting/intermediate type creation, so it's picked.

Comment: @Lærne Yeah, I can see that, yet `{0}` is not an `int` is it? Which is why clang issues that warning?

Comment: @OliverSchönrock `{0}` is also not `std::initializer_list`

Comment: If you change first function to accept a `int&` as argument then in the case of `{0}` it will pick the `initializer_list` https://godbolt.org/z/YnabTqrnb

Comment: In this situation the best `T` such that `foo(T{0})` is `T = int`, so yes, _here_, `{0}` is an `int`. But `0` would work as well, hence the warning.

Comment: @Giogre it's because you cannot bind temporary to lvalue reference `int&`

Comment: @Lærne OK... so which of these is it? 

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution

Comment: @appleapple yeah changing type to a "ref to int" is just a workaround, but in that case you are sure a `initializer_list` gets chosen if that's OP's aim.

Comment: @Giogre if OP can change the signature, it's more directly to add an overload to `std::initializer_list` (which doesn't even need to change existing function) (and one would most likely want to invoke a function with temporary int)

Comment: @Giogre or, ofcourse, explicitly specify the temporary type in the call side would also work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{0}` doesn't have a type, so we need to try and convert it to the parameter types of the overload set.  When considering

```
void foo([[maybe_unused]] const std::vector<int>& v) {}
```

We need to consult [[over.ics.list]/7.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over#ics.list-7.2) which states

> Otherwise, the implicit conversion sequence is a user-defined conversion sequence whose second standard conversion sequence is an identity conversion.

so we have a user defined conversion for this conversion sequence.

Looking at

```
void foo([[maybe_unused]] int i) {}
```

We find the conversion covered in [[over.ics.list]/10.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over#ics.list-10.1) which states

> if the initializer list has one element that is not itself an initializer list, the implicit conversion sequence is the one required to convert the element to the parameter type;

The element in this case is `0`, which is an integer literal which is an exact match standard conversion

So now we have a user defined conversion vs a standard conversion and that is covered by [[over.ics.rank]/2.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over#ics.rank-2.1)

> a standard conversion sequence is a better conversion sequence than a user-defined conversion sequence or an ellipsis conversion sequence, and

and now we know that the standard conversion is a better conversion and that is why the `int` overload is chosen over the `std::vector<int>` overload.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was after... Thanks, that makes it clear.

Comment: @OliverSchönrock You're welcome.  Overload resolution is a very tough topic to digest.  I still find myself surprised from time to time with all of the corner cases there are.

Comment: Is there any way to "encourage" the compiler... other than changing the argument type at the call site to `std::initializer_list<int>`

Comment: @OliverSchönrock Encourage the compiler to do what?

Comment: .. to pick the `foo(std::vector)` overload when I want to pass a single element

Comment: @OliverSchönrock Ah, not that I know of besides using a `std::initializer_list<int>` parameter but that would be preferred over even the `std::vector` overload.  The standard committee made the decision to treat `{ single_value }` only as a list if no other overload is valid, as normally when you have a list you have more then one item and a single item means you want a single object.  For instance with  `auto foo = { 0 };` `foo` gets deduced to `int`, not `initializer_list<int>`, but with `auto bar = { 1 , 42 };` `bar` is an `std::initializer_list<int>`.

Comment: Yeah, fair. I can see how they came to that conclusion. Inconvenient here, but fair enough. Thanks